# Django ORM with Key/Value Table structure

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I'm trying to get the django orm to replicate a call on a database for my current table structure:

Tables:

ServiceItems {Id, name, user, date_created}

ServiceItemsProps {fk_to_ServiceItems Item_id, Id, key, value}

I'm trying to select items from the ServiceItem table with multiple keys from the ServiceItemsProps table as columns.

I can accomplish this with a query like the following:

```
> select tbl1.value as bouncebacks, tbl2.value as assignees from
> service_items join service_item_props as tbl1 on tbl1.item_id =
> service_items.id join service_item_props as tbl2 on tbl2.item_id =
> service_items.id where service_items.item_type='CARD' and
> tbl1.key='bouncebacks' and tbl2.key='assignees'
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to reproduce this in Django's ORM.  I would like to not inject raw SQL into the statements here, because codebase portability is important.

Section of models.py

```
class ServiceItems(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'service_items'
        unique_together = ('service', 'item_type', 'item_id')

    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, blank=False, db_column='service_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    item_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    item_creation_user = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    item_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class ServiceItemProps(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'service_item_props'

    item = models.ForeignKey(ServiceItems, blank=False, db_column='item_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prop_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    value = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: can you add models.py ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge  I've added the fields definitions from the file

Answer (score 1):

```
# change one line to make it easier to query
item = models.ForeignKey(ServiceItems, blank=False, db_column='item_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item_props')
```

Query should become:

```
ServiceItem.objects.filter(Q(item_type='CARD') & (Q(item_props__key='bouncebacks') | Q(item_props__key='assignees'))
```

==============================================================

I think I misunderstood your query.

I believe this is a good case to use `.raw()` .

Try this one instead:

```
qs = ServiceItemProps.objects.raw('''
SELECT sip1.*, sip2.value as other_value
FROM {item_table} as service_items
    INNER JOIN {props_table} as sip1 on sip1.item_id = service_items.id
    INNER JOIN {props_table} as sip2 on sip2.item_id = service_items.id
WHERE service_items.item_type='CARD' and sip1.key='bouncebacks' and sip2.key='assignees'
'''.format(item_table=ServiceItems._meta.db_table, props_table=ServiceItemProps._meta.db_table)


for itemprop in qs:
    print(qs.value, qs.other_value)
```

Comment: oh u need to `from django.db.models import Q` and documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Comment: That does save me a ton of trouble, but it still doesn't return the values for those keys.

Comment: Maybe I didn't fully understand the requirements here, try this `print(ServiceItem.objects.filter(Q(item_type='CARD') & (Q(item_props__key='bouncebacks') | Q(item_props__key='assignees')).query)` to print the sql behind it to see where the logic is wrong

Comment: That filters to ServiceItems where the properties match the query, what I want is a single row for each ServiceItem that also contains the values for multiple ServiceItemProps

Comment: I believe this is the case to use the raw query, please check the updated answer.

Comment: So, there isn't a pure orm solution to this problem?

Comment: Looking at updates for Django 2.0, it seems that this can be accomplished through filtered annotations.  See this link in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations